# How to navigate through directories using c++ to create a file explorer

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, ncurses

I'm trying to create a file explorer in C++ using Ncurses for my class. Currently I'm trying to find a way to navigate through the file system and find out if 'x' is file/directory and act accordingly.

The problem is I can't find a way to navigate through directories they way I'd like. For example, in the code below I start at "." and then read it while saving some info of said directory and its files. But I'd like to define the cwd to "/home" everytime  the program runs and then go from there exploring whatever the user wants like:

> display /home -> user selects /folder1 -> display /folder1 -> user selects /documents -> ...

I've read about scripts and tried to create a "cd /home" script but it doesn't work. Somewhere I read that the execve() function might work, but I don't understand it. I've got a feeling that I'm overthinking this, and frankly I'm stuck.

edit: In essence I'd like to find: How to make it so that my program starts at "path" so that when I call getcwd() it returns "path" and not the actual path of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "contenido.cpp"
using namespace std;

//Inicia main

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  DIR *dir;                       //dir is directory to open
  struct dirent *sd;
  struct stat buf;                //buf will give us stat() atributes from 'x' file.
  char currentpath[FILENAME_MAX]; //currentpath
  contenido dcont;

  //system (". /home/rodrigo/Documentos/Atom/Ncurses/Proyecto/beta/prueba.sh");

  if((dir = opendir(".")) == NULL){ /*Opens directory*/
    return errno;
  }
  if(getcwd(currentpath, FILENAME_MAX) == NULL){
    return errno;
  }

  while ((sd= readdir(dir)) != NULL){ /*starts directory stream*/
    if(strcmp(sd -> d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(sd -> d_name,"..") ==0){
        continue;
    }

    //Gets cwd, then adds /filename to it and sends it to a linked list 'dcont'. Resets currentpath to cwd
    //afterwards.
    getcwd(currentpath, FILENAME_MAX);
    strcat(currentpath, "/");
    strcat(currentpath, sd->d_name);
    string prueba(currentpath);
    //std::cout << currentpath << '\n';
    dcont.crearnodo(prueba);
    if(stat(currentpath, &buf) == -1){
      cout << currentpath << "\n";
      perror("hey");
      return errno;
    }
    getcwd(currentpath, FILENAME_MAX);

    //Prints Files and Directories. If Directory prints "it's directory", else prints "file info".
    if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
      cout << sd->d_name << "\n";
      cout << "ES DIRECTORIO\n";
    }else
    cout << sd->d_name << "\n";
    cout <<"Su tamaño es: " << (int)buf.st_size << "\n";
    //system("ls");

  }


  closedir(dir);
  dcont.mostrardircont(); //prints contents of the linked list (position in list and path of file).
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to always use full (not relative) paths.  Then it just becomes an exercise in string manipulation.

Comment: @Ron How to make that my program starts at "path" so that when I call getcwd() it returns "path" and not the actual path of the program.

Comment: @Ron thanks for the help, sorry if I wasn't very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your current working directory use chdir
If you want to change your cwd to "/home"
chdir("/home");

Comment: So apparently I was overthinking it... If I use chdir("/home") at the beginning of main would it remain as /home until another chdir() function was called? Would I get "/home" if I call the getcwd() function?

Comment: If you stay within your application. When your app exits it will return to the original wd

Answer (score 0):

The chdir only persists within the program that did it (or subprocesses).  It won't cause the shell to change.  There's an application ([wcd](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/)) which does something like what you're trying, which combines the navigation with a shell script.